# YUI get specific cell value when selecting a row to fire event

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, dom-events, yui

I am using Yahoo UI library, in particular this [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_rowselect.html).

What I want is to get a particular column's value when clicking (selecting) a row.

I am using this code:

```
var makis = function() {alert("blabla"); };
myDataTable.subscribe("rowClickEvent", makis);
```

and works, but I just don't know how to get a column's value in the particular row.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at the docs? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html

Comment: i am already looking but i cant make it work. THats why i am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found it on my own, i am posting if anyone has the same problem.

```
myDataTable.subscribe("rowClickEvent", function(oArgs) {
                                        var elTarget = oArgs.target;
                                        var oRec = this.getRecord(elTarget);
                                        console.log("value:" + oRec.getData("column_we_want"));
                                }
```